# Space for widget which not exist

Tags: cyanogenmod, app-widgets

My problem is that I want to delete space for the widget which is shown in below screenshot. Any hints how can I remove it? I have got CyanogenNod 12.01 (Android 5.1.1).

[image: the thing I want to delete]
<sup>the thing I want to delete (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: The widget should be the google searchbar I guess - please check if you have the following settings available: "Settings - Display & LED - Searchbar in Recent Apps". The titles may vary as I've translated it to englisch. If this settings is available, then disable it and the widget should be removed.

Comment: @benjaminS please add this comment as an answer, you helped me with your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Widget is normally the **google searchbar**.
If it is missing - the chances are high that you've removed the Google application from your phone. The missing widget can't be found and the empty box with the error message appears as we can see in your screenshot.

Luckily you are running cyanogenmod which lets you **hide this widget from the recent apps screen**. To do this go to:

> **Settings > Display & LED > Searchbar in Recent Apps**

Disable the option and the widget should be gone.

---

*I'll try to add screenshots when I get home this evening.*